# Post nested dictionary when key is the same

Tags: python, dictionary, request, nested

I am trying to post multiple entries on a time tracking app called Toggl, and to do so, I figured I need to post a nested dictionary, but the key value ('time_entry') needs to remain the same. Can anyone help me figure out how to post a nested dictionary when the key needs to remain the same?

Code:

```
data = { 
    "time_entry": 

        { 
            "description":"LOL Meeting 2",
            "wid":2758150,
            "start":"2020-07-11T14:00:00.000Z",
            "duration":3600,
            "pid":156855752,
            "created_with":"python",
            "tags":["Coaching"],
            
           
        },
        "time_entry":

         
       { 
            "description":"LOL Meeting",
            "wid":2758150,
            "start":"2020-07-11T13:00:00.000Z",
            "duration":3600,
            "pid":156855752,
            "created_with":"python",
            "tags":["Coaching"]
            
        }
       
        
}



response = toggl.postRequest("https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/time_entries", parameters=data)
```

From this code, as you can expect only one entry is submitted, but I need both

Comment: `dict` cannot have duplicate keys. Use a `list` of `dicts`

Comment: Can't you post them one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

`data` could be a list of dicts as follow:

```
data = [{ 
            "description":"LOL Meeting 2",
            "wid":2758150,
            "start":"2020-07-11T14:00:00.000Z",
            "duration":3600,
            "pid":156855752,
            "created_with":"python",
            "tags":["Coaching"]
        },
           { 
            "description":"LOL Meeting",
            "wid":2758150,
            "start":"2020-07-11T13:00:00.000Z",
            "duration":3600,
            "pid":156855752,
            "created_with":"python",
            "tags":["Coaching"]
            
        }]
```

As you can see, you won't need the `key:  time_entry`